# Magento 2 - extension attributes interface

Tags: magento2, cart, totals, extension-attributes

I'm trying to add an extension attribute to `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface`. My understanting is, that magento should generate `getter/setter` for the new attribute, but that is not happening. (i tried deleting `var/generation` `var/cache` multiple times)

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface">        
        <attribute code="custom_attribute" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Is my understanding correct, or is this just not possible?

The interface is instantiated using factory in `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository`. Could that have an effect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The getters and setters are not added to the `TotalsInterface` itself.

Instead they are generated in `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsExtensionInterface` (which you should find in `var/generation`) and you use it like this (for `custom_attribute`):

```
$totals->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomAttribute();
```

Comment: That is exactly what i would expect to happen. However TotalsExtensionInterface.php is never generated.

Comment: Not at all, not even empty? Are you running in developer mode? Are other classes generated?

Comment: I'm running developer mode. The file is not there but others are (TotalsInterfaceFactory, TotalSegmentExtension etc).

getExtensionAttributes() returns null so i assume the attribute is not registered? I have no idea why that is.

Comment: Weird, it should be there. I don't fully understand when these are generated, maybe http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93366/how-does-magento2-generate-the-specific-extensionfactory-and-extensionattributei?rq=1 is helpful in that case

Comment: Ok thanks for  your time, the information provided is correct. It is working now, but i have no idea what changed.

What i did:
1, Reinstalled magento and update 2.0.5 to 2.0.7
2, ran setup:di:compile - again my extension interface is not generated
3, reformatted my extension_attributes.xml (with ide and also removed the line break)
4, ran setup:di:compile - the interface gets generated T_T

Number of generated files in /Magento/Quote/Api/Data is much greater than before. (not sure if that's caused by version update)